# How to add wysiwyg editor in pyrocms module

Tags: codeigniter, fckeditor, pyrocms

I have developed a `PyroCMS` custom module, but now I want to add `WYSIWYG` editor instead of the text area.

How can I add it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just append this while building the template in the controller.

```
->append_metadata($this->load->view('fragments/wysiwyg', $this->data, TRUE))
```

and then

```
echo form_textarea(array('id' => 'body', 'name' => 'code', 'value' => '', 'rows' => 30, 'class' => 'wysiwyg-advanced'));
```

Hopefully this will help you sometime..

Answer (score 1):

Update:

With PyroCMS 2.2, `$this->data` has been deprecated.

In your controller you would need to change

```
->append_metadata($this->load->view('fragments/wysiwyg', $this->data, TRUE))
```

to

```
->append_metadata($this->load->view('fragments/wysiwyg', compact('items'), TRUE))
```

Comment: This only works in the backend/admin not the frontend. Any idea how to make it work?